# Not getting all ids using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to pull the id values from the `div` between `<div id="rxn-input" style="position: absolute; display: block; left: 20px; top: 452.036px;">`. Below is the html code:

```
<div id="rxn-input" style="position: absolute; display: block; left: 20px; top: 452.036px;">
<div style="position: relative; outline: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <div style="position: absolute; outline: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-size: 13px; font-family: sans-serif; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); background: transparent; top: 0px; left: 0px; overflow: hidden; visibility: visible;"></div>
    <input type="text" spellcheck="false" style="font-size: 13px; font-family: sans-serif; color: rgb(170, 170, 170); background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238); width: 100%; outline: 0px; border: 0px transparent; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; box-shadow: none;">
    <input type="text" spellcheck="false" style="font-size: 13px; font-family: sans-serif; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); background-color: transparent; width: 100%; outline: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; vertical-align: top; position: relative;">
    <div style="position: absolute; visibility: visible; outline: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left; font-size: 13px; font-family: sans-serif; background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238); z-index: 100; cursor: default; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170); overflow-x: hidden; white-space: pre; overflow-y: scroll; left: 0px; top: 100%; max-height: 457.969px;">
        <div id="2AGPEAT120" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221); outline: 0px;"><b>2AGPEAT120</b> 2agpe120_c + atp_c + ddca_c → <b>amp_c</b> + pe120_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="2AGPEAT140" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); outline: 0px;"><b>2AGPEAT140</b> 2agpe140_c + atp_c + ttdca_c → <b>amp_c</b> + pe140_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="2AGPEAT160" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); outline: 0px;"><b>2AGPEAT160</b> 2agpe160_c + atp_c + hdca_c → <b>amp_c</b> + pe160_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="2AGPEAT161" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>2AGPEAT161</b> 2agpe161_c + atp_c + hdcea_c → <b>amp_c</b> + pe161_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="2AGPEAT180" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>2AGPEAT180</b> 2agpe180_c + atp_c + ocdca_c → <b>amp_c</b> + pe180_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="2AGPEAT181" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>2AGPEAT181</b> 2agpe181_c + atp_c + ocdcea_c → <b>amp_c</b> + pe181_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="2AGPGAT120" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>2AGPGAT120</b> 2agpg120_c + atp_c + ddca_c → <b>amp_c</b> + pg120_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="2AGPGAT140" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>2AGPGAT140</b> 2agpg140_c + atp_c + ttdca_c → <b>amp_c</b> + pg140_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="2AGPGAT141" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>2AGPGAT141</b> 2agpg141_c + atp_c + ttdcea_c → <b>amp_c</b> + pg141_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="2AGPGAT160" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>2AGPGAT160</b> 2agpg160_c + atp_c + hdca_c → <b>amp_c</b> + pg160_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="2AGPGAT161" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>2AGPGAT161</b> 2agpg161_c + atp_c + hdcea_c → <b>amp_c</b> + pg161_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="2AGPGAT180" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>2AGPGAT180</b> 2agpg180_c + atp_c + ocdca_c → <b>amp_c</b> + pg180_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="2AGPGAT181" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>2AGPGAT181</b> 2agpg181_c + atp_c + ocdcea_c → <b>amp_c</b> + pg181_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="AACPS1" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>AACPS1</b> ACP_c + atp_c + ttdca_c → <b>amp_c</b> + myrsACP_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="AACPS2" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>AACPS2</b> ACP_c + atp_c + ttdcea_c → <b>amp_c</b> + ppi_c + tdeACP_c</div>
        <div id="AACPS3" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>AACPS3</b> ACP_c + atp_c + hdca_c → <b>amp_c</b> + palmACP_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="AACPS4" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>AACPS4</b> ACP_c + atp_c + hdcea_c → <b>amp_c</b> + hdeACP_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="AACPS5" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>AACPS5</b> ACP_c + atp_c + ocdcea_c → <b>amp_c</b> + octeACP_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="AACPS6" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); outline: 0px;"><b>AACPS6</b> ACP_c + atp_c + ocdca_c → <b>amp_c</b> + ocdcaACP_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="AACPS7" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>AACPS7</b> ACP_c + atp_c + ddca_c → <b>amp_c</b> + ddcaACP_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="AACPS8" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>AACPS8</b> ACP_c + atp_c + dca_c → <b>amp_c</b> + dcaACP_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="AACPS9" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>AACPS9</b> ACP_c + atp_c + octa_c → <b>amp_c</b> + ocACP_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="ACS" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>ACS</b> ac_c + atp_c + coa_c → accoa_c + <b>amp_c</b> + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="ADK1" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>ADK1</b> <b>amp_c</b> + atp_c ↔ 2 adp_c</div>
        <div id="ADK3" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>ADK3</b> <b>amp_c</b> + gtp_c ↔ adp_c + gdp_c</div>
        <div id="ADK4" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>ADK4</b> <b>amp_c</b> + itp_c ↔ adp_c + idp_c</div>
        <div id="ADNK1" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>ADNK1</b> adn_c + atp_c → adp_c + <b>amp_c</b> + h_c</div>
        <div id="ADPRDP" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>ADPRDP</b> adprib_c + h2o_c → <b>amp_c</b> + 2 h_c + r5p_c</div>
        <div id="ADPT" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>ADPT</b> ade_c + prpp_c → <b>amp_c</b> + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="ADSL1r" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>ADSL1r</b> dcamp_c ↔ <b>amp_c</b> + fum_c</div>
        <div id="ALATRS" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>ALATRS</b> ala__L_c + atp_c + trnaala_c → alatrna_c + <b>amp_c</b> + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="AMPN" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>AMPN</b> <b>amp_c</b> + h2o_c → ade_c + r5p_c</div>
        <div id="ARGSS" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>ARGSS</b> asp__L_c + atp_c + citr__L_c → <b>amp_c</b> + argsuc_c + h_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="ARGTRS" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>ARGTRS</b> arg__L_c + atp_c + trnaarg_c → <b>amp_c</b> + argtrna_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="ASNS1" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>ASNS1</b> asp__L_c + atp_c + gln__L_c + h2o_c → <b>amp_c</b> + asn__L_c + glu__L_c + h_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="ASNS2" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>ASNS2</b> asp__L_c + atp_c + nh4_c → <b>amp_c</b> + asn__L_c + h_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="ASNTRS" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>ASNTRS</b> asn__L_c + atp_c + trnaasn_c → <b>amp_c</b> + asntrna_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="ASPTRS" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>ASPTRS</b> asp__L_c + atp_c + trnaasp_c → <b>amp_c</b> + asptrna_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="BPNT" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>BPNT</b> h2o_c + pap_c → <b>amp_c</b> + pi_c</div>
        <div id="CYSTRS" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>CYSTRS</b> atp_c + cys__L_c + trnacys_c → <b>amp_c</b> + cystrna_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="ENTCS" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>ENTCS</b> 3 23dhba_c + 3 seramp_c → 6 <b>amp_c</b> + enter_c + 9 h_c</div>
        <div id="FACOAL100t2pp" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>FACOAL100t2pp</b> atp_c + coa_c + dca_p + h_p → <b>amp_c</b> + dcacoa_c + h_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="FACOAL120t2pp" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>FACOAL120t2pp</b> atp_c + coa_c + ddca_p + h_p → <b>amp_c</b> + ddcacoa_c + h_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="FACOAL140t2pp" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>FACOAL140t2pp</b> atp_c + coa_c + h_p + ttdca_p → <b>amp_c</b> + h_c + ppi_c + tdcoa_c</div>
        <div id="FACOAL141t2pp" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>FACOAL141t2pp</b> atp_c + coa_c + h_p + ttdcea_p → <b>amp_c</b> + h_c + ppi_c + tdecoa_c</div>
        <div id="FACOAL160t2pp" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>FACOAL160t2pp</b> atp_c + coa_c + h_p + hdca_p → <b>amp_c</b> + h_c + pmtcoa_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="FACOAL161t2pp" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>FACOAL161t2pp</b> atp_c + coa_c + h_p + hdcea_p → <b>amp_c</b> + h_c + hdcoa_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="FACOAL180t2pp" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>FACOAL180t2pp</b> atp_c + coa_c + h_p + ocdca_p → <b>amp_c</b> + h_c + ppi_c + stcoa_c</div>
        <div id="FACOAL181t2pp" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>FACOAL181t2pp</b> atp_c + coa_c + h_p + ocdcea_p → <b>amp_c</b> + h_c + odecoa_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="FACOAL60t2pp" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>FACOAL60t2pp</b> atp_c + coa_c + h_p + hxa_p → <b>amp_c</b> + h_c + hxcoa_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="FACOAL80t2pp" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>FACOAL80t2pp</b> atp_c + coa_c + h_p + octa_p → <b>amp_c</b> + h_c + occoa_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="GDPDPK" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>GDPDPK</b> atp_c + gdp_c → <b>amp_c</b> + h_c + ppgpp_c</div>
        <div id="GLNTRS" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>GLNTRS</b> atp_c + gln__L_c + trnagln_c → <b>amp_c</b> + glntrna_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="GLUTRS" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>GLUTRS</b> atp_c + glu__L_c + trnaglu_c → <b>amp_c</b> + glutrna_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="GLYTRS" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>GLYTRS</b> atp_c + gly_c + trnagly_c → <b>amp_c</b> + glytrna_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="GMPS2" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>GMPS2</b> atp_c + gln__L_c + h2o_c + xmp_c → <b>amp_c</b> + glu__L_c + gmp_c + 2 h_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="GTPDPK" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>GTPDPK</b> atp_c + gtp_c → <b>amp_c</b> + gdptp_c + h_c</div>
        <div id="HISTRS" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>HISTRS</b> atp_c + his__L_c + trnahis_c → <b>amp_c</b> + histrna_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="HPPK2" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>HPPK2</b> 6hmhpt_c + atp_c → 6hmhptpp_c + <b>amp_c</b> + h_c</div>
        <div id="ILETRS" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>ILETRS</b> atp_c + ile__L_c + trnaile_c → <b>amp_c</b> + iletrna_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="LYSTRS" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>LYSTRS</b> atp_c + lys__L_c + trnalys_c → <b>amp_c</b> + lystrna_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="METTRS" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>METTRS</b> atp_c + met__L_c + trnamet_c → <b>amp_c</b> + mettrna_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="NADDP" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>NADDP</b> h2o_c + nad_c → <b>amp_c</b> + 2 h_c + nmn_c</div>
        <div id="NADS1" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>NADS1</b> atp_c + dnad_c + nh4_c → <b>amp_c</b> + h_c + nad_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="NTD7" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>NTD7</b> <b>amp_c</b> + h2o_c → adn_c + pi_c</div>
        <div id="NTPP6" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>NTPP6</b> atp_c + h2o_c → <b>amp_c</b> + h_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="PACCOAL" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>PACCOAL</b> atp_c + coa_c + pac_c → <b>amp_c</b> + phaccoa_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="PANTS" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>PANTS</b> ala_B_c + atp_c + pant__R_c → <b>amp_c</b> + h_c + pnto__R_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="PDE1" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>PDE1</b> camp_c + h2o_c → <b>amp_c</b> + h_c</div>
        <div id="PHETRS" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>PHETRS</b> atp_c + phe__L_c + trnaphe_c → <b>amp_c</b> + phetrna_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="PPS" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>PPS</b> atp_c + h2o_c + pyr_c → <b>amp_c</b> + 2 h_c + pep_c + pi_c</div>
        <div id="PROTRS" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>PROTRS</b> atp_c + pro__L_c + trnapro_c → <b>amp_c</b> + ppi_c + protrna_c</div>
        <div id="PRPPS" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>PRPPS</b> atp_c + r5p_c ↔ <b>amp_c</b> + h_c + prpp_c</div>
        <div id="SELNPS" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>SELNPS</b> atp_c + h2o_c + seln_c → <b>amp_c</b> + pi_c + selnp_c</div>
        <div id="SERTRS2" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>SERTRS2</b> atp_c + ser__L_c + trnasecys_c → <b>amp_c</b> + ppi_c + sertrna_sec_c</div>
        <div id="SERTRS" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>SERTRS</b> atp_c + ser__L_c + trnaser_c → <b>amp_c</b> + ppi_c + sertrna_c</div>
        <div id="SUCBZL" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>SUCBZL</b> atp_c + coa_c + sucbz_c → <b>amp_c</b> + ppi_c + sbzcoa_c</div>
        <div id="THRTRS" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>THRTRS</b> atp_c + thr__L_c + trnathr_c → <b>amp_c</b> + ppi_c + thrtrna_c</div>
        <div id="THZPSN" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>THZPSN</b> atp_c + cys__L_c + dxyl5p_c + tyr__L_c → 4hba_c + 4mpetz_c + ala__L_c + <b>amp_c</b> + co2_c + h2o_c + h_c + ppi_c</div>
        <div id="TRPTRS" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>TRPTRS</b> atp_c + trnatrp_c + trp__L_c → <b>amp_c</b> + ppi_c + trptrna_c</div>
        <div id="TYRTRS" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>TYRTRS</b> atp_c + trnatyr_c + tyr__L_c → <b>amp_c</b> + ppi_c + tyrtrna_c</div>
        <div id="VALTRS" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>VALTRS</b> atp_c + trnaval_c + val__L_c → <b>amp_c</b> + ppi_c + valtrna_c</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the code I am using:

```
d3.selectAll("#rxn-input")
    .selectAll("div").each(function (d) {
        new_sel.push(d3.select(this).attr("id"));
});
```

However, I am only getting the IDs of 85 `div`s but there are 1600 `div`s present. I am not sure why I am not getting the ids for the rest.

Comment: The html you pasted has 83 `id="`strings. no more.

Comment: I really hope you don't try to copy/paste 1600 divs in your question.

Comment: I assume your problem is the following: `id` is short for *identifier*, which means any specific id can only reside on **one** html element. If you put the same id on more than one element, selecting via id only retrieves the first element with that given id. In short, you cannot have more than one `div id="rxn-input"` in your HTML.